# Select by integer range in splitted string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and I currently have following problem:

I have a table "offers" where a user can place an offer to another user where he offers him ingame items. The items are placed into the datafield with the ItemID and ItemLevel separated by a ":" and the itemes by a ",".

Example: "0:346,2:638,1:646" = offers Item with ID 0 Level 346 and ID 2 Level 638 and ID 1 Level 646

Now I want to create a query with PHP to SELECT only offers with specific IDs and a range of Level.

Should I rebuild the whole thing and do it with 2 different tables "orders" and "order_data" or is it possible to make this filtering possible by a simple query?

Comment: Definitely fix your data-model, in the long run it will be easier than a "simple query".

Comment: Thanks for the great input, i see your point and will rebuild it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must normalize your data... As you say, you should distribute the orders data between multiple tables and columns.

However, there's a possible (and simple) solution for your request:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE 1=1
AND FIND_IN_SET('0:346', orderData)
;
```

`FIND_IN_SET` function **returns the index of the searched string** - if it exists on column - so it's usually used as a `SELECT` field in order to know string's index on comma separated string. But, as in this case, **you can use it on `WHERE` clause in order to return only the records that contains the specific string**.

Comment: Thanks this looks like a great and helpful tip :) However its not fully fitting what i exactly need since i need to search for EXACT ids but RANGE levels. ;)

Comment: In that case rebuild your db model :) it's the best solution.
Cheers.